# Show that $\mathbb{E}[ | X - \mathbb{E}[X] | ] \ge c > 0$ if $\mathbb{V}(X) = 1$?

Tags: probability

I have a random variable $X$ with unit variance, i.e. $\mathbb{V}(X) = 1$. Is there a positive constant $c > 0$ such that
$$\mathbb{E}[\ | X - \mathbb{E}[X] | \ ] \ge c > 0  ?$$
How do we prove it? If it is false, can we find a counter-example?

Comment: By using double bars for the norm, are you trying to imply $X$ is a vector-valued random variable?  In that case, what exactly does it mean for its variance to be "$1$"?

Comment: I edited the question to include single bars for the absolute value. I am only looking for the scalar case.

Comment: Consider a symmetric variable with center 0 and probability mass at 0 and two symmetrically placed points, with mass $1-2\epsilon$ at 0 and $\epsilon$ at the two other points with distance from 0 chosen to make the variance 1. Compute the mean deviation as a function of  $\epsilon$.

Comment: Thanks @Glen_b, this is a great counterexample! So in this case $\kappa \in \{ -\sqrt{\frac{2}{\varepsilon}}, + \sqrt{\frac{2}{\varepsilon}}\} $ are the points that makes the variance equal to one, and $\mathbb{E}[|X - \mathbb{E}[X]|] = 2 \kappa \varepsilon = 2^{3/2}\sqrt{\varepsilon}$. We can then choose $\varepsilon$ arbitrarily close to zero. This argument seems to rely on $X$ being unbounded. Do you think that if $X$ is bounded then there would be a $c$ as in the question?

Comment: $X$ is bounded at each value of $\epsilon>0$. You don't have to let  $\epsilon$ go all the way to zero --- whatever $c$ is you can just choose a corresponding small but positive $\epsilon$ (and hence, finite $\kappa$) that contradicts the potential claim in relation to $c$. [Incidentally, I've not seen this question before; its a matter of thinking about how to make the variance big relative to the mean deviation, which is obviously to have a lot of probability in the middle and then  push a little probability far away from that, which inflates variance much more than mean deviation]

Comment: You might consider writing up an answer; it looks like you figured out the main details.

Comment: Thanks @Glen_b!

Answer (score 3):

I will go ahead and formalise the answer in the comments from [Glen_b](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/805/glen-b).  For any value $0 < \epsilon \leqslant \tfrac{1}{2}$ we can define a discrete random variable $X$ with mass function:

$$\mathbb{P}(X=x)
= \begin{cases} 
\epsilon & & & \text{for } x = -\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2 \epsilon}}, \\[6pt]
1-2\epsilon & & & \text{for } x = 0, \\[10pt]
\epsilon & & & \text{for } x = \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2 \epsilon}}, \\[10pt]
0 & & & \text{otherwise}. \\[6pt]
\end{cases}$$

This random variable has zero mean and has variance:

$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{V}(X)
= \mathbb{E}(X^2)
&= (-\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2 \epsilon}})^2 \cdot \epsilon + 0 \cdot (1-2\epsilon) + (\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2 \epsilon}})^2 \cdot \epsilon \\[6pt]
&= \tfrac{1}{2 \epsilon} \cdot \epsilon + \tfrac{1}{2 \epsilon} \cdot \epsilon \\[8pt]
&= \tfrac{1}{2} + \tfrac{1}{2} = 1. \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

For this random variable we have:

$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(|X - \mathbb{E}(X)|)
&= \mathbb{P}(|X|) \\[8pt]
&= |-\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2 \epsilon}}| \cdot \epsilon + |0| \cdot (1-2\epsilon) + |\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2 \epsilon}}| \cdot \epsilon \\[6pt]
&= \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2 \epsilon}} \cdot \epsilon + \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2 \epsilon}} \cdot \epsilon \\[6pt]
&= \sqrt{\tfrac{\epsilon}{2}} + \sqrt{\tfrac{\epsilon}{2}} \\[6pt]
&= \sqrt{2\epsilon}. \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

Now, since we can use any value $0 < \epsilon \leqslant \tfrac{1}{2}$ for this analysis, there is no positive lower bound for this probability --- i.e., its lower bound is zero.

Comment: Great! Thanks for writing down a formal answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let $Y = X-\mathbb{E}(X)$. Then by Chebyshev's inequality, for any $k > 0$, $P(|Y-\mathbb{E}[Y] | \geq k) \leq 1/k^{2} \geq P(|Y| \geq k)$. By Chebyshev's inequality, think you can reach a contradiction.

Comment: Chebyschev's inquality helps us prove that $\mathbb{E}[|X - \mathbb{E}[X]|]$ has an upper bound but not that it has a lower bound.